# gpg-agent is older than us: how to find "us"?

Tags: gnupg

From what I understand, the `gpg-agent is older than us` warning happens when the gpg-agent version doesn't match the gpg version, often because there are two gpg-agents installed (and sharing the socket). Other answers I saw about this warning usually boil down to uninstalling the old gpg-agent or restarting it after an update. I have the opposite problem: I can't find what is this "us" that has a newer version.

```
$ pass email
gpg: WARNING: server 'gpg-agent' is older than us (2.2.27 < 2.2.32)
```

It's not just with `pass`, any use of gpg shows the warning. As far as I can tell, the only gpg and gpg-agent are the ones from the ubuntu repository:

```
$ gpgconf
gpg:OpenPGP:/usr/bin/gpg
gpg-agent:Private Keys:/usr/bin/gpg-agent
scdaemon:Smartcards:/usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon
gpgsm:S/MIME:/usr/bin/gpgsm
dirmngr:Network:/usr/bin/dirmngr
pinentry:Passphrase Entry:/usr/bin/pinentry
```

When I use gpg, it is indeed those binaries that I'm calling:

```
$ which gpg
/usr/bin/gpg

$ which gpg-agent
/usr/bin/gpg-agent
```

They are both version 2.2.27:

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.4

$ gpg-agent --version
gpg-agent (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.9.4
```

If I uninstall gpg-agent, I can't use my gpg key anymore:

```
$ sudo apt remove gpg-agent
$ pass email
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

If I uninstall gpg, there's no other gpg:

```
$ sudo apt remove gpg
$ gpg --version
Command 'gpg' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install gpg
```

I tried to find if there was any other gpg binary in the path (I used to have newer versions installed with `guix`), and there aren't:

```
$ for folder in $PATH
$     find $folder -name "gpg*"
$ end
/usr/bin/gpg
/usr/bin/gpg-agent
/usr/bin/gpg-connect-agent
/usr/bin/gpg-wks-server
/usr/bin/gpgcompose
/usr/bin/gpgconf
/usr/bin/gpgparsemail
/usr/bin/gpgsm
/usr/bin/gpgsplit
/usr/bin/gpgtar
/usr/bin/gpgv
```

I ran `gpgconf --kill all`, `systemctl --user restart gpg-agent`, restarted the computer many times, but the warning persists.

So how do I find this mysterious gpg with version 2.2.32, or what else could be causing the warning?

Comment: Is there a chance that another version of `gpg` was installed from source, with homebrew or a similar solution? Maybe check `ls -la /usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Thanks for the idea. There used to be one installed with guix, but I removed it a while ago. `/usr/local/bin` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is going to be very specific to my case (being a guix user), but it turns out I do have gpg 2.2.32 on my system, even if it's not in the path, because it is a dependency of `pass`. Since I installed it using guix, `pass` (and the other software complaining about the version mismatch) is patched to call this specific version of `gpg` using its absolute path, instead of looking for `gpg` in `$PATH`.

To look for any version of `gpg` remaining in the gnu store:

```
$ find /gnu/store/ -type d -name '*gnupg-*'
/gnu/store/97xv2yyswpiq6p2mlm5zqdk23q8z8sdh-gnupg-2.2.32
```

To figure out which package depends on it:

```
$ guix gc --referrers /gnu/store/97xv2yyswpiq6p2mlm5zqdk23q8z8sdh-gnupg-2.2.32
/gnu/store/yiyhfm10gldx1g5lqyys49r6czna22dj-password-store-1.7.4
```

And this is indeed the `pass` I'm using:

```
$readlink (which pass)
/gnu/store/yiyhfm10gldx1g5lqyys49r6czna22dj-password-store-1.7.4/bin/pass
```

So in the case of users of guix over a foreign distribution, the possible choices are:

- Continue to use ubuntu's `gpg-agent`, guix's `gpg` client, and live with the warning if it doesn't prevent anything to work.
- Continue to use ubuntu's `gpg-agent`, and don't use any `guix` package depending on `gnupg` to ensure we use only ubuntu's `gpg` client.
- Stop using ubuntu's `gpg-agent` and use guix's instead. To disable ubuntu's service and make sure nothing will restart it:

  `$ systemctl --user mask --now gpg-agent.service gpg-agent.socket gpg-agent-ssh.socket gpg-agent-extra.socket gpg-agent-browser.socket`

  In my experience, uninstalling ubuntu's `gpg-agent` will only work temporarily, I think until ubuntu checks for updates and wants to verify signatures.

  It's fine to not explicitly install `gnupg` on the guix side: it seems `pass` will automatically start guix's `gpg-agent`. Problems only arise when both `gpg-agent` have to share the socket.